# using jquery in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

the chrome extension i am building gets the selected text from the tab open when the user clicks on the select button in popup.I am trying to use jquery for this.

Manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "cap",
  "description": "BLAH",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [ "tabs",
    "https://*/*","http://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["selection.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }
 ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup_main.html"
  }
}
```

I have included the jquery script in popup.html

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>popup</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/popup.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tag-it.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>

</body></html>
```

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function (response) {
      var text = document.getElementById('text'); 
      text.innerHTML = response.data;
    });
  });
  });
});
```

on executing this script i am geting the error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

please help!

Answer (score 13):

You need to change the order of your script tag to allow jQuery to load first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Change the order .You have to load the jquery core plugin first and then then other plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```